# NodeJS exiting prematurely

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a NodeJS child process listening for messages with `process.on('message', callback)` however the process is exiting immediately. From my reading this is not supposed to happen since I have a callback waiting on the event loop so why is NodeJS exiting?

The example code below should be able to run as a standalone NodeJS process and not exit, correct?

Node Version: 7.3.0

example code:

```
function handle(msg) {
    //do work here
}

process.on('message', (msg) => {
    handle(msg);
}
```

Comment: Can you give us a little more information - how is this code run? And when you say exit, does the program itself exit? Is this a standalone script or a server? If you'd check the documentation for the `message` event - https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_message - you'd notice that it is fired only when the Node process is spawned via IPC.

Comment: The example is pretty much it.. I spawn the script above using child process.fork and the child process just exits after executing the script but I'm wanting it to stay alive listening for messages to handle some work in the seperate spawned process rather than spawning a new process each time i need the work done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample program that emulates your problem.

*master.js*

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const child = cp.spawn('node', ['./child.js'], {stdio: ['ipc']})
child.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(data.toString()))
child.send('immediate execute MESSAGE 1')
setTimeout(() => {
    child.send('late execute MESSAGE 2 after 4 seconds')
}, 4000)
```

*child.js*

```
function handle(msg) {
    console.log('Handling message -> ', msg);
}

process.on('message', (msg) => {
    handle(msg);
});

process.on('exit', () => {
    process.disconnect();
});
```

The key things to note here are -

1. `child_process.spawn` - spawn returns a Buffer, and you can start listening to the stdout stream as soon as the child process starts.
2. `{stdio: ['ipc']}` - this option lets you open an IPC channel with the spawned child process. When you want to disconnect the child, simply use `child.disconnect()`.